Show that "dichotomizing" a continuous outcome variable reduces the standardized effect size
We have been teaching sample size calculation for the comparison of two groups A and B.  I was asked to provide a mathematical explanation of why it reduces power to "dichotomize"  a continuous outcome variable $Y$ by choosing a cutoff $C$ and comparing the proportions with $Y > C$.  It is enough to show that the standardized effect size for a z-test comparison of means will always be larger than the standardized effect size for a z-test comparison of the corresponding proportions.   I may assume that Y is normally distributed with variance $\sigma^2 = 1$.
Assume that:
$$\text{Mean of Group A} = 0$$
$$\text{Mean of Group B} = E$$
The standardized effect size for the z-test comparison of means is:
$$
\text{Effect Size} = \frac{\text{Mean of Group B} - \text{Mean of Group A}}{\sqrt{\sigma^2}} = \frac{E - 0}{1} = E
$$
Now, assume that we dichotomize the continuous variable $Y$ at a threshold $C$. The proportion of individuals in Group A with $Y > C$ is given by:
$$
p_A = 1 - \Phi(C)
$$
Similarly, the proportion of individuals in Group B with $Y > C$ is:
$$
p_B = 1 - \Phi(C - E)
$$
$\Phi(\cdot)$ represents the CDF of the standard normal distribution.

The difference in proportions between the two groups is:
$$
D = p_B - p_A = \left[1 - \Phi(C - E)\right] - \left[1 - \Phi(C)\right] = \Phi(C) - \Phi(C - E)
$$
The variance of this difference is:
$$
V = p_A(1 - p_A) + p_B(1 - p_B)
$$
Thus, the standard deviation of the difference is:
$$
S = \sqrt{V}
$$
Finally, the standardized difference (effect size) after dichotomizing is:
$$
\text{Standardized Difference} = \frac{D}{S}
$$
If my reasoning this far is correct, I just need to show that, for arbitrary C and E, both > 0,
\begin{align*}
E &> \frac{D}{S} \\
 &> \frac{\Phi(C) - \Phi(C - E)}{\sqrt{\Phi(C)( 1 - \Phi(C)) + \Phi(C - E)(1 - \Phi(C - E))}}
\end{align*}
From experimentation, the inequality holds. I can't prove it.  Is my reasoning correct?  If so, how do I show that the inequality holds?
